Fragment Container View Loose NavGraph
I have a function to create a new bottom sheet dialog in my main activity which contain a fragment container view to display a nav graph.
    private fun showBottomSheet() {
        // Create the BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)

        // Inflate the layout for the Bottom Sheet (this is the correct layout)
        val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_add_address, null)

        // Set the content view for the BottomSheetDialog
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView)
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }

Everything work fine at the first time render screen but i did notice that my fragment container loose it nav graph after i collapse and re open the dialog, the dialog still have it's fragment container but the nav graph is gone.
I have tried to locate the issue with the activity and the first fragment of the graph lifecycle and see that the fragment did call onResume but only 1 time (the second time i open the bottom sheet dialog) but still not showing anything, after that onResume never been called again. Notice that, fragment onStop or onDestroy never been called even when i collapse the bottom sheet
I usually use bottom sheet fragment so i really dont have a clue what the problem is, if anyone can help me with this problem it would be great.
Here is my git project if you guys want a closer look: Project's Repository
Thank you guys in advance.

You should use FragmentContainerView in the activity's layout.
In your project move add_address_bottom_sheet_fragmentContainerView to the activity_main.xml

Is there a reason you aren't using BottomSheetDialogFragment, which does clean up after itself when you dismiss it?

I usually try BottomSheetDialogFragment yes, but i just found out BottomSheetDialog and want to try it to know the difference between them

Thank you for your suggestion, Mohammadreza Khahani
So here is a solution i have been suggested so far, remove the fragment container view from bottom sheet dialog xml and add it into activity and let the activity handle the fragment container state instead the dialog.
So basically i visibility gone or remove the fragment container at the onCreate method then add the fragment container view into the add address dialog. This certainly not a good solve for this problem but a nice quick work around.
Here is my MainActivity.kt
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var fab: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var rcv: RecyclerView
    private val viewModel: AddressViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var repo: AddressRepo
    private lateinit var adapter: HouseAdapter
    // create a global variable container the container view
    private lateinit var fragmentContainerView: FragmentContainerView
    private val TAG: String = "Activity Main log"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        fab = binding.homeFab
        rcv = binding.homeRcv

    // bind and remove the view in onCreate
        fragmentContainerView = binding.homeFragmentContainerView
        (fragmentContainerView.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(fragmentContainerView)

        val db = DatabaseInstance.getDatabase(this@MainActivity)
        repo = AddressRepo(db.addressDao())

        adapter = HouseAdapter(emptyList())
        rcv.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        val spacingInPixels = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_spacing)
        rcv.addItemDecoration(ItemDecoration(2, spacingInPixels, true))
        rcv.adapter = adapter

        // Load data asynchronously and update the adapter
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val addresses = repo.getAllHouse()
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: House Data = " + addresses.toString())
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                adapter.updateData(addresses)
            }
        }

        viewModel.address.observe(this) {address ->
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: INPUT = $address")
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            showBottomSheet()
        }
    }

    private fun showBottomSheet() {
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)

        val bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_add_address, null)

    // add container into bottom sheet dialog if it parent is null
        if (fragmentContainerView.parent != null) {
            (fragmentContainerView.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(fragmentContainerView)
        }
        fragmentContainerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val bottomSheetLinearLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet_placeholder_container)
        bottomSheetLinearLayout.addView(fragmentContainerView)

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView)
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }

    }

My acivity layout
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Screen.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_rcv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/home_fragmentContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:background="@color/lightGrey"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/add_address"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_fab_description"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add"
        app:tint="@color/white"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

My bottom sheet add address layout
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetDragHandleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_placeholder_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.example.customviews.StepBar
            android:id="@+id/add_address_bottom_sheet_progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
            app:barColor="@color/lightBlue"
            app:canGoUpTo="3"
            app:currentStep="3"
            app:inactiveBarColor="@color/lightGrey"
            app:inactiveMockColor="@color/grey"
            app:mockColor="@color/blue"
            app:stepCount="5" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

